# hibernate hbm2ddl=validate skip sequence validation

Tags: hibernate

We have our hibernate application on 2 enviroments A(with sequences) and B(without sequnces).
On B we do not create any entities and there is no sequences by design.
The problem is that we can't deploy application on B because hibernate validation fails on sequence check.
Is there any way to skip validation for sequences?